# What is the relation between curvature in the plane en the geodesic curvature of a curve on a sphere?

Tags: geometry

We are looking for a relation between de geodesic curvature of a curve in Euclidian sphere in 3 dimensions and the curvature of a curve in Euclidian plain.

We tried to find the relation with the help of a conformal map between the sphere and the plane $\mathbb S^2$, but we could not find the exact relation yet.

We expect a relation where $\kappa = (\mathrm{something}) \times \kappa_{g}$,

such that the derivative of normal curvature en geodesic curvature are equal in the same points.